# panic handling or what has happend

Tags: go, panic

I don't understand what is the best way to handle panics. I can write my own `panic("bad data or empty source")` and I'll detetrmine on the output that code fails on this exactly place, but what to do with the panic's that are generated in not mine methods.

Now I have such an error :

```
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/panic.go:26 (0x4975a4) handleInvocationPanic: c.Response.Out.Write(debug.Stack()) 
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/panic.go:12 (0x4b60ca) PanicFilter.func1: handleInvocationPanic(c, err) 
c:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:437 (0x45cc75) call32: CALLFN(·call32, 32) 
c:/go/src/runtime/panic.go:423 (0x42ec17) gopanic: reflectcall(nil, unsafe.Pointer(d.fn), deferArgs(d), uint32(d.siz), uint32(d.siz)) 
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/intercept.go:93 (0x4b6061) InterceptorFilter.func1: panic(err)
c:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:437 (0x45cc75) call32: CALLFN(·call32, 32)
c:/go/src/runtime/panic.go:423 (0x42ec17) gopanic: reflectcall(nil, unsafe.Pointer(d.fn), deferArgs(d), uint32(d.siz), uint32(d.siz))
c:/go/src/runtime/panic.go:42 (0x42d280) panicmem: panic(memoryError)
c:/go/src/runtime/signal_windows.go:161 (0x44233d) sigpanic: panicmem()
C:/gocode/src/github.com/oculus/libs/funcs.go:13 (0x4e0ca5) GetDatesInRange: fmt.Println(err.Error())
C:/gocode/src/github.com/oculus/rest/app/controllers/kpi.go:97 (0x4e3b2f) KpiCtrl.GetNoagg: dates, errors := libs.GetDatesInRange(request.Filters.DayStart, request.Filters.DayEnd) :97 (0x4e9f12)
c:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:437 (0x45cc75) call32: CALLFN(·call32, 32)
c:/go/src/reflect/value.go:432 (0x471591) Value.call: call(frametype, fn, args, uint32(frametype.size), uint32(retOffset))
c:/go/src/reflect/value.go:300 (0x470258) Value.Call: return v.call("Call", in)
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/invoker.go:36 (0x496e51) ActionInvoker: resultValue = methodValue.Call(methodArgs)[0]
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/compress.go:47 (0x487f89) CompressFilter: fc[0](c, fc[1:])
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/intercept.go:103 (0x4954b9) InterceptorFilter: fc[0](c, fc[1:])
C:/gocode/src/github.com/oculus/rest/app/init.go:37 (0x4e2366) glob.func1: fc[0](c, fc[1:]) // Execute the next filter stage.
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/i18n.go:155 (0x4947a3) I18nFilter: fc[0](c, fc[1:])
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/validation.go:191 (0x4ae27d) ValidationFilter: fc[0](c, fc[1:])
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/flash.go:46 (0x490ee7) FlashFilter: fc[0](c, fc[1:])
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/session.go:149 (0x4a914c) SessionFilter: fc[0](c, fc[1:])
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/params.go:133 (0x499116) ParamsFilter: fc[0](c, fc[1:])
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/filterconfig.go:208 (0x490a64) FilterConfiguringFilter: fc[0](c, fc[1:])
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/router.go:474 (0x4a61e6) RouterFilter: fc[0](c, fc[1:])
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/panic.go:15 (0x4972c8) PanicFilter: fc[0](c, fc[1:])
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/watcher.go:232 (0x4b512d) glob.func31: fc[0](c, fc[1:])
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/server.go:50 (0x4a6d95) handleInternal: Filters[0](c, Filters[1:])
C:/gocode/src/github.com/revel/revel/server.go:38 (0x4a68f6) handle: handleInternal(w, r, nil)
c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1422 (0x57cfe1) HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP: f(w, r)
c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1862 (0x57f285) serverHandler.ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1361 (0x57ca85) (*conn).serve: serverHandler{c.server}.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
c:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1721 (0x45f121) goexit: BYTE  $0x90   // NOP
```

How should I work with them, or how to determine where is the trouble. this is not enformative for me for this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Go` you have the possibility to recover from panic, which does contain the panic error message. After recovering you may analyze the issue why the panic is happening. To recover from panic you can use the `defer` statement which as the name implies, defers execution of the statement. This means that you can skip some events to hang up the system, which is not quite a good solution. The best solution is to capture the errors and handle them adequately. If the error happens on some third party framework this should be addressed by their creators. If not you should check why your code is panicking.

Here a code snippet for panic recover:

```
defer func() {
    if err := recover(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Recovered from panic. %s", err)
    }
}()
```

And here is a simple example of how you can use the build in panic and recovery methods:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func badCall() {
    panic("Bad call happend!")
}

func test() {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Panicking %s\n\r" , err)
        }
    }()

    badCall()
    fmt.Println("This is never executed!!")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start testing")
    test()
    fmt.Println("End testing")
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/Uz9W76SfRT

If recover is called inside a deferred function, the stack stops unwinding and recover returns the value (as an `interface{}`!) that was passed to panic. This means that you can pass an interface as an argument to the panic method, like:

```
type ParseError struct {
    Index int    // The index into the space-separated list of words.
    Word  string // The word that generated the parse error.
    Error error  // The raw error that precipitated this error, if any.
}

// String returns a human-readable error message.
func (e *ParseError) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("pkg: error parsing %q as int", e.Word)
}

// ... some code
if err != nil {
    panic(&ParseError{idx, field, err})
}
// ... some code
```

Then you can analyze the passed interface in the deferred statement.

Read this article:
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PanicAndRecover

Comment: Where should i use it, if i'm writing on framework like revel. Or, can you give me an example of simple code that can generate panic, and where you will handle it with a way that you suggest? Like example that can be ran at go playground : https://play.golang.org/

Comment: @Altenrion please see a sample code for how you can use panic and recovery.

Comment: Your snippet is great, but it illustrates the case, when i have the panic with custom  message. What if some library would get wrong params , and panic? Would it behave in the same way, or instead of the message would me the stacktrace like in my questiin?

Comment: @Altenrion if you are writing a framework, or generally reusable code, avoid using panic. Use errors instead. Panics are most often used when irrecoverable situations arise. Normal failures are best handled as return values from called functions.

Comment: Thanks for examples and links. I'll check them on my code in the morning, and will tell the results.

Comment: Tested, but "idx" and "field" id second example, they must be defined, wright? go says "undefined... " so what should I make with them

Comment: Speaking of the first snippet, it helps a lot with my own panics, to see them in terminal, so I'll count this answer, but still interresting how to handle this all panics in more centralised manner. I mean that not to see them in log, but for example to return them exception like... or maybe write in errors channel on server, and another deamon would be listening for errors coming and reporting anywhere..

Comment: Did you checked the example provided? "idx" and "field" are in fact the indices and values of the slice slice.

Comment: Yes I checked, but second example i didn't  understand =(

Answer (score 1):

You can use this piece of code and place it in every function

```
defer func() {
  if err := recover(); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Panic Occured and Recovered in, Error Info: ", err)
  }
}()
```

Try this it will work for you.